# Using Ito's lemma to determine Expected value and Variance of GBM

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

> Example: The most popular way to model single stocks is a Geometric Brownian motion (GBM):
> $$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + S \sigma dW_t$$
>
> 1. Determine $\mathbb{E}[S_t]$
> 2. Determine $\text{var}[S_t]$
>
> Tip: The MGF $\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)]$ when $X \sim N(a,b^2)$ is given by $\exp(at+ \frac{b^2t^2}{2})$. Use the result for $X = \log(S)$ using Ito's lemma.

I am trying to understand the steps they take to solve the questions but I don't quite understand what they are doing and how they are using Ito's lemma or knowledge about GBM.

1. Using Ito's lemma we know that the solution of the SDE describing the share price $S$ as a GBM is:
   $$S_t = S_0\exp(X)$$
   with
   $$X = (\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t.$$

Hence: $\mathbb{E}[S_t] = S_0\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$ with $X \sim N((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t, \sigma^2t).$ Using definition of the MGF of $X$:
$\mathbb{E}[S_t] = S_0 \varphi_X(1)$ with
\begin{align*}
\varphi_X(1) &= \exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2})\\
&= \exp(\mu t)
\end{align*}
Therefore $\mathbb{E}[S_t] = S_0 \exp(\mu t)$.

2. For the variation they use $\mathbb{E}[S_t^2] = S_0^2 \mathbb{E}[\exp(2X)]$ which uses what they did in 1. but I also don't understand it there.
   The rest of this part I do understand.

Comment: Well isn't this $\varphi_X(2)$ ?

Comment: By the way there is a typo in $\varphi_X(1) = \exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2})$ it should be : $\varphi_X(1) = \exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \frac{\sigma^2.t}{2})$ (as the notation is confusing time with $t=1$ coefficient used in the Laplace transform)

Answer (score 1):

So what is $\varphi_X(2)$ worth ?
$$\varphi_X(2)=exp(2.(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+2^2.\sigma^2.t/2)=exp(2.(\mu)+\sigma^2.t(2-1))=exp(2t.(\mu)+\sigma^2.t)= exp(2.a +4.b^2)$$  and as $a=\mu.t$ (see below) you get $$b=\sqrt{(2t.\mu+\sigma^2.t -2a)}/2=\frac{\sigma\sqrt{t}}{2}$$

BTW :
$$\varphi_X(1)=exp(1.(\mu-\sigma^2).t+1^2.\sigma^2.t/2)=exp((\mu-\sigma^2/2).t+\sigma^2.t/2))=exp(\mu.t)$$ so as $a=\mu.t$